# How to fix version conflict for MicrosoftEntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I create a WEB API in .NET CORE with the 'dotnet new' command. i want to configure this with Entity Framework Core but i cant. I install this with the 'Manage Nugets Pakages' in VS2017 and VS give me a error.

I tried to restore packages but the error persist.

my csproj file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CORE\CORE.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DAL\DAL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DOORACCESS\DOORACCESS.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DPFINGER\DPFINGER.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\LOGIC\LOGIC.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\utest\utest.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

As you can see download the packages but do not add them to the csproj. I tried to do it manually, but when I put it in, I was asking for its dependencies one by one.

Comment: Because you are using `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` this means that you need to use packages of version `2.1.x`. Anything that is `2.2.x` will error. I think I use this version of [EF](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.1.8) for my .net2.1 app

Comment: You said "give me a error" but you didn't specify the error message you're receiving. While we can guess what the problem might be, it's impossible to give a definite answer without an exact error message.